# How can I do a page load to open modal dialog box on Sharepoint Online 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have created a Survey app on my page of my Sharepoint Online 2013. For that, I want to display them on a Modal Dialog box upon loading a web page. Please advise me with javascripts or jquery suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inbuilt modal popup functionality of SharePoint which SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog

Try this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-modal-dialog-pop-up-in-sharepoint-2016-and-office-365/)

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
    });  

    function showModalPopUp() {  
        //Set options for Modal PopUp  
        var options = {  
            url: '/sites/HOL/Pages/Custom-Publishing-Page.aspx?IsDlg=1', //Set the url of the page  
            title: 'SharePoint Modal Pop Up', //Set the title for the pop up  
            allowMaximize: false,  
            showClose: true,  
            width: 600,  
            height: 400  
        };  
        //Invoke the modal dialog by passing in the options array variable  
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);  
        return false;  
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Shridhar, thanks for the scripts! It work well to what i needed!